# In App purchase failed with error Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I use store kit with in app purchase and everything was perfect, but since the
last week every time i clicked purchase button (sandbox or testFlight) it did
this :

1. Show login view to fill password
2. Waiting a bit
3. Re-show login view to fill password
4. Then it failed with error "Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}"

Anyone can help me here please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an on-going issue on iOS versions below iOS 14.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/98763?page=2

Seems that the messages are not sorted by most recent... please check page 2? *shrug*